Biblatex AMA style with authoryear in text
The journal which I am submitting to requires a combination (seemingly) of reference types.
It calls for the format [author (et al.,), year] with the square brackets in text. I have managed to do this using the authoryear biblatex style and citing like [\cite{}].
However, the bibliography they require seems to be in AMA format:
Paivio A, Jansen B, Becker LJ. Comparisons through the mind's eye. Cognition 1975;37(2):635-47
Does anyone know how I could implement this in biblatex? I really appreciate the help.

There is a repository that contains the necessary changes to make biblatex support the AMA reference style. The repository is available here: biblatex-ama. You can follow the installation instructions, which are straightforward:

Copy both ama.bbx and ama.cbx to the root of your project.
Include the following in your preamble: \usepackage[citestyle=ama, bibstyle=ama]{biblatex}

To use the [Author et al., Year] citation style, you must modify both files.
In the ama.cbx file, make the following changes:
\ProvidesFile{ama.cbx}[2021/07/09 v0.1 biblatex bibliography style]

% Use authoryear style for citations [MODIFIED by @joseareia]
\RequireCitationStyle{ext-authoryear}

% First after last name
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

% No punctuation inside names
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

% Cite with square brackets [MODIFIED by @joseareia]
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelimsAlias{cite}{parencite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

In the ama.bbx file, simply modify the parameters passed in ExecuteBibliographyOptions as follows:
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=none, maxbibnames=6, minbibnames=3, maxcitenames=2, 
mincitenames=1, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false,
giveninits=true, terseinits=true}

Here's a MWE.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[citestyle=ama, bibstyle=ama]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{TeX Exchange}
\author{José Areia}
\date{November 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Example In-Text Citation}
Here is an example of an in-text citation: \cite{paivio1975}.

\section*{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

It produces the following.

I hope this works for you and helps you.

Please note that new questions should not be asked in comments. Thats why we have "ask a new question" button :-)) Comments should only be used to clear unclear questions if possible ...

My apologies. I will revise the answer to align with the established guidelines. Thank you for the helpful warning.

You are welcome!

Thank you Jose! That worked great.

I'm pleased to hear that. Consider marking this answer as correct.
